# Machine Learning - implementing a Gradient Descent in Python from Octave code

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, octave, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement a gradient descent function in Python from scratch which I have implemented and work in GNU Octave. Unfortunately I am stuck. I fiddled with it for a while and checked the NumPy documentation but so far no luck.
I am aware of libraries such as scikit-learn, however my purpose is to learn to code such a function from scratch. Perhaps I am going about it the wrong way.
Below you will find all the code necessary to reproduce the error.
Thanks in advance for your help.

**Actual result**: test fails with error ->  "ValueError: matmul: Input operand 0 does not have enough dimensions (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)"

**Expected result**: and array with values [5.2148, -0.5733]

Function gradientDescent() in Octave:

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)
        m = length(y); % number of training examples
        J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

        for iter = 1:num_iters
          theta = theta - (alpha/m)*X'*(X*theta-y);
          J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);
        end
```

Function gradient_descent() in python:

```
from numpy import zeros

def compute_cost(X, y, theta):
    m = len(y)
    ans = (X.T @ theta).T - y
    J = (ans @ ans.T) / (2 * m)
    return J[0, 0]


def gradient_descent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters):
    m = len(y)
    J_history = zeros((num_iters, 1), dtype=int)
    for iter in range(num_iters):
        theta = theta - (alpha / m) @ X.T @ (X @ theta - y)
        J_history[iter] = compute_cost(X, y, theta)
    return theta
```

the test file: test_ml_utils.py

```
import unittest
import numpy as np
from ml.ml_utils import compute_cost, gradient_descent

class TestGradientDescent(unittest.TestCase):
    # TODO: implement tests for Gradient Descent function
    # [theta J_hist] = gradientDescent([1 5; 1 2; 1 4; 1 5],[1 6 4 2]',[0 0]',0.01,1000);
    def test_gradient_descent_00(self):
        X = np.array([[1, 5], [1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 5]])
        y = np.array([1, 6, 4, 2])
        theta = np.zeros(2)
        alpha = 0.01
        num_iter = 1000
        r_theta = np.array([5.2148, -0.5733])
        result = gradient_descent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iter)
        self.assertEqual((round(result, 4), r_theta), 'Result is wrong!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 3):

The `__matmul__` operator `@` in Python binds more tightly than `-`. That means you're trying to do matrix multiplication with the operands `(alpha / m)`, which is a scalar, and `X.T`, which is actually a matrix. See [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

In the Octave code, `(alpha - m) * X'` is doing scalar multiplication, not matrix, so if you want that same behavior in Python, use `*` rather than `@`. This seems to be because Octave overloads the `*` operator to perform scalar multiplication if one operand is a scalar, but matrix multiplication if both operands are matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Adam's answer (which is correct in regards to the error you're getting).

However I wanted to add more generally, this code is meaningless to a reader without some sort of hint (whether programmatically or in the form of a comment) what dimensions the different variables take.

E.g., there is a hint in the code that `y` is likely to be 2-dimensional, and you're using `len` to get its size. Just as an example of how this might fail silently, consider this:

```
>>> y = numpy.array([[1,2,3,4,5]])
>>> len( y )
1
```

whereas presumably you want

```
>>> numpy.shape( y )
(1, 5)
```

or

```
>>> numpy.size( y )
5
```

I note in your unit test that you're passing a rank 1 vector instead of rank 2, so it turns out y is 1D instead of 2D, but operates with X which is 2D due to broadcasting. Your code therefore works despite the logic implied, but in the absence of making such things explicit, this is a runtime error waiting to happen.